# Migration from Spring Boot 2.6 to 2.7 - FlywayException: Unsupported Database: Microsoft SQL Server 15.0

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, maven, flyway

During migration of a Java app using Spring Boot 2.6 to 2.7, new Flyway version (8.5.13) seems to not support anymore SQL Server 15 (2019).

> Error
> org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: Microsoft SQL Server 15.0

I try with older version of SQL Server 14 (2017) and get almost same error

> Error
> org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: Microsoft SQL Server 14.0

Somebody already resovled this problem?

Comment: Do you have the `flyway-sqlserver` dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL Server code was extracted to a separate dependency in [Flyway 8.1.0](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#8.1.0)

From that release onwards, you will need to [add flyway-sqlserver](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/sqlserver#java-usage) as an additional dependency, e.g.:

```
# Maven
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-sqlserver</artifactId>
</dependency>

# Gradle
dependencies {
    compile "org.flywaydb:flyway-sqlserver"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed working now. Other little thing, I had to add `encrypt=false` in JDBC connection url. I know it's not ideal, but DB server is not in my hands.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @codemonkey they decided to separate the dependencies.

Here a list of flyway database dependencies (which are managed in spring-boot-dependencies)

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>${flyway.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-database-oracle</artifactId>
    <version>${flyway.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-firebird</artifactId>
    <version>${flyway.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>${flyway.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-sqlserver</artifactId>
    <version>${flyway.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Overview application pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-database-oracle</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Overview application properties:

```
# FlyWay
spring.flyway.user=dbUser
spring.flyway.password=dbPwd
spring.flyway.schemas=dbSchema
spring.flyway.url=dbConnectionString
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/oracle/scripts
```

Console log:

```
Started FlywayApplication in 7.562 seconds (process running for 8.049)
```